# Redirect stdout/stderr for each thread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I like to redirect output from stdout for each thread to a file. The following code redirect all thread output to a single file -

```
int fd = open(<filename_threadid.txt>, <flags>)
_dup2(fd, 1)
```

How should I restore the original stdout so the next thread can reliably map its stdout to the filename_threadid?

Comment: That sounds really dangerous and non-standard. Can't your threads just write to well-defined files using standard methods?

Comment: You might look into a good logging framework like Boost.Log

Answer (score 9):

On all platforms the [standard streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) (stdin, stdout, stderr) are per process. As such they cannot be redirected per thread. You should modify your code so that each thread outputs to a specific file instead of the stdout.

Answer (score 1):

I use a `fork()` inside the thread for redirect the stdout of the forked process while the "true" thread is in `waitpid()`.
The problem is how to pass the file where you want to redirect stdout.
I use a global thread pool, and the thread will find itself through `pthread_equal(pthread_self(),iterator)`, then in the global thread pool structure there is the outfile where the program should redirect the stdout.
In my case I create a `tmpnam()` and write it to the thread struct, but you can use it how you wish.

Here is some example code: (written on the fly)

```
pthread_t *t_cur=NULL;
int i,pid,newout;
char *outfile=NULL;

for(i=0;i<MAX_THREADS;i++)
  if(pthread_equal(pthread_self(),globals.tpool[i]->thread))
    break;
if(i==MAX_THREADS)
{
   printf("cannot find myself into global threads pool.\n");
   pthread_exit(&i);
 }
if(globals.tpool[i]->outfile == NULL) //  redirect stdout only if outfile is not set ( this is specfic for my purposes )
{
  outfile = globals.tpool[i]->outfile = malloc(L_tmpnam*sizeof(char));
  tmpnam(outfile);
}

if((pid = fork()) == 0)
{
   if(outfile!=NULL)
   {
     newout = open(outfile,O_CREAT | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP);
     dup2(newout,STDOUT_FILENO);
     close(newout);
   }
   /* your code here */
}
else
  waitpid(pid,NULL);
pthread_exit(&i);
```

I really wrote it on the fly, I haven't tested this code, so take care to fix any errors. I didn't post my real code because of calls to my own library. Here I didn't check the return values from `tmpnam()`, `fork()`, `open()` and `malloc()`, which you should do.