# Change default output stream on argp

Tags: c, glibc

By default [argp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html) uses stdout.

In the argp-parse.c source code, you can see that in the init function the value is initialized to stdout:

```
parser->state.out_stream = stdout;
```

The struct argp_state is internally used argp and stores the value [out_stream](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_node/libc_526.html).

I would like to change the default behaviour and redirect the stream to another file descriptor.

Comment: What software are you talking about?

Comment: [The GNU C Library: Argp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is redirect `stdout` and restore it later:

```
int orig_stdout = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
extern int my_other_file_descriptor;
dup2(my_other_file_descriptor, STDOUT_FILENO);

// parse args

dup2(orig_stdout, STDOUT_FILENO);
```

Comment: I've already tried this and it works, but there is one big problem to this solution: [all the threads of the process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811132/redirect-stdout-stderr-for-each-thread) will redirect their stdout.

I would like a solution that does not force me to do so.

Comment: @lorenzod Why would you even start any threads _before_ parsing command line arguments?

Comment: I'm trying to use argp to build an interactive custom command line interface. Therefore I don't use it just once at the bootstrap of the program.

Comment: @lorenzod You are building a multithreaded argument parser? I think a little more context would be helpful here to help us give you good advice.

Comment: I just need to redirect argp stdout to another file pointer.
The constraint I've to impose regarding the dup2 is due to the fact that I'll be parsing argument coming runtime from a Unix Domain Socket that are collected by a thread in a multi-threaded application. 
Based on what I've seen in the argp code, the value of stdout (and stderr) seems to be hardcoded and not configurable anyhow.